# Get Upgrade queue SP 2013

Tags: 2013, upgrade

is there a way to get all ContentDbs/site-collections which are currently queued for upgrade via Sharepoint Management shell?

I am having issues where upgrade of one of my site-collections doesn't start so i'm guessing there's an upgrade in queue which is stuck or something...

Comment: Did you check Manage databases Upgrade Status (/_admin/DatabaseStatus.aspx) in Central admin?

Comment: @Prasanna yes they all have status no action required. So very strange situation

Comment: Do you see anything in ULS logs related to this issue?

Comment: Nope just sharepoint doing his thing when it's idle nothing related to an update. When I "start" a new update I can fetch it with Get-SPUpgradeSessionInfo cmd but it doens't start. So I was thinking something else is in front it in the queue. but I haven't got a clue what that could be.

Comment: What's the HTTP status code you get when accessing the site URL? Are you able to access site settings page (/_layouts/15/settings.aspx)?

Comment: Yeah everything works as it should just the upgrade site collection doens't start. It's very strange I've done other content db's in the past days all with no problem

Answer (score 0):

In the end it turned out SharePoint had not finished a previous upgrade as it should which blocked my next update in the queue. Solution to starting my next update was as follows

> Upgrade-SPSite -Identity "YourSiteCollectionURL" -Unthrottled

-Unthrottled
Specifies a farm administrator to bypass the throttle which permits a site collection to be upgraded even if there are "too many" site collections in the throttle to be upgraded.